# Azure Mobile App Help Page Asking for Username and Password

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have created an Azure Mobile App from the new Azure portal. Then I host my C# API to it. When I open Azure Mobile URL in browser it says **This mobile service is up and running**. This means it's working fine. After this I hit **Try it out** button to test the app. Then it shows an popup to enter username and password. (**See image**).

I have checked each and everything on portal to get this username and password but there is no option to get it.

**Authentication / Authorization**: App Service Authentication is set to **Off**.

[image: What to enter and where to find]

Comment: Do any of your APIs have an [Authorize] decoration?  If that is the case, and you have not set up authentication, then the server will return a 401 Unauthorized which will cause the pop-up

Answer (score 0):

The Try it Out page is part of the Azure Mobile Services .NET nuget packages, **not** Azure Mobile Apps. For a list of the versions of the client and server SDKs, see [Client and server versioning in Mobile Apps and Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/). To summarize, Mobile Services packages have the ID [WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend) and the newer Mobile Apps packages have the ID [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server/).

Somehow, you have deployed a Mobile Services project to your service. You should instead download the server project from the Azure Portal (the new Azure Portal), and deploy that. Alternatively, you can create a new Mobile Apps project in Visual Studio.